# Microsoft Access: Cannot add record (s); join key of 'Computer' not in recordset

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Relationship of the database: here:
[image: here]

Form of the database: here:
[image: here]

So the problem is that when I enter data from "Client's name" field to "Phone number" field everything's alright, but when I try to enter data in "Manufacturer" field, it says: `Microsoft Access: Cannot add record(s); join key of 'Computer' not in recordset`.

Comment: Include `Computer ID` in your query of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have field Computer on your Form.